# Replacement for the ring seal or gasket in a blender

Tags: equipment

I have a Moulinex blender and the seal ring or gasket is torn. I have searched everywhere to get a replacement. is there a replacement or is Oster the only seal rings I can get. Is there a DIY solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could cut one from an appropriately sized piece of rubber.  I have a couple of palm-sized pieces of rubber for gripping jars that would probably do the trick.